# Photo browser WPF app - performance improvements

Tags: c#, performance, image, wpf

I'm working on WPF photo broswer app as a personal project. I realise my current strategy for thumbnail handling is poor as I read in the full image each time -- this shows when browsing a folder with more than a few images. If anybody can suggest changes that might improve this aspect of the code, or anything else, that would be very useful.

A slimmed down version of the code is below. This takes a folder and displays thumbnails and names of the images within it. (The full app also has buttons to perform various operations on the images.)

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace PhotoBrowser
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }

    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private string _folder;
        public string Folder
        {
            get => _folder;
            set
            {
                _folder = value;
                if (Directory.Exists(_folder))
                {
                    var filesInFolder = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_folder);
                    var files_ = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
                    foreach (string file in filesInFolder)
                    {
                        files_.Add(new FileItem(file, false));
                    }
                    Files = files_;
                }
                else
                {
                    Files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
        {
            get => _files;
            set
            {
                _files = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel() { }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PhotoBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoBrowser"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Photo Browser" Height="800" Width="800" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Folder"
                       Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Folder" 
                    Text="{Binding Folder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="5,5,5,5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="FilesInCurrentFolder" 
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                BorderBrush="Black" Height="Auto" Width="772" SelectionMode="Extended"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Files, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**FileItem.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace PhotoBrowser
{
    public class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private string _fileName;
        public string FileName
        {
            get => _fileName;
            set
            {
                _fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => Path.GetFileName(_fileName);
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                _fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(_fileName), value);
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private BitmapSource _thumbnail;
        public BitmapSource Thumbnail
        {
            get => _thumbnail;
            set
            {
                _thumbnail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public FileItem(string fileName)
        {
            this.FileName = fileName;
            GetThumbnail();
        }

        public FileItem(string fileName, bool isSelected) : this(fileName)
        {
            this.IsSelected = isSelected;
        }

        public void GetThumbnail()
        {
            Image image = new Bitmap(FileName);
            image = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thumbnail = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a shell interface you can use to get thumbnail images from the windows shell. IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of your property setters are doing too much.  For example in `MainWindow`, the `Folder` property setter doesn't just set the folder name but it also takes time to enumerate and collect all files within that folder.  This goes against the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and perhaps the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  I have used such applications like that and get frustrated that when all I wanted to do was navigate to a folder but each click seems to force reads from a folder.  In short, setting a folder should only set a folder, and enumerating the files in that folder should be a separate action.

Performance could benefit from implementing some async calls and keep somethings streaming.  You stream with `EnumerateFiles` but you add them to a list.  This can take a performance hit. I would investigate the exact instant you think you need to read files, and delay reading them right up until that instant.

You should read up on any async methods associated with `BitMap`.  I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709382/async-load-bitmapimage-in-c-sharp) how how to load a bitmap asynchronously with C#.  And you might consider using a background Task to enumerate files or load thumbnails.